# Dynamic dropdown creation in excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create two drop down where the first one will have Years and the second one will have months. If I select year 2015, 2nd dropdown should display only months from Jan to Sep. If I select year 2014, 2nd drop down should display all months. Could any one of you help me to od this in excel?

Comment: so .. you're saying if they select the current year, they can only select up to the current month ? (just trying to clarify your requirements .. you make it sound like a hard list there .. but I'm thinking it's going to move with the current date ?)

Comment: Yes Ditto. you are correct

Comment: Ok, that confirms the largest date you are allowed ... what's the oldest ? How far back are they allowed to pick ? 2000?  1950 ? 1900 ?

Comment: My intention to show last 60 months. which means last 5 years(2010-oct to 2015 sep). that means if we select 2010, months drop down should have only Oct to Dec.

Comment: Ok, I wouldn't handle this with 2 drop downs, I'd recommend using a single date field, and use data validation between those dates you just indicated.  Do a google search for "excel drop down calendar" .. there's a few tutorials that allow you to put a drop down calendar in Excel .. fairly simple and looks pretty professional.  :)  (FYI  You let them pick a date, you just ignore the "day" .. ;)  )

Answer (score 0):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub DVSetup()
    Range("A1:B1").Clear
    With Range("A1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="2014,2015"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

    For i = 1 To 12
      Range("C" & i).Value = Format(DateSerial(2000, i, 1), "mmm")
    Next i

    With Range("B1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=IF(A1=2014,C1:C12,C1:C9)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

It sets up *DV* in cell **A1** to allow a pick between 2014 and 2015.  It also sets up *DV* in cell **B1** to allow the correct month range for each year selected in **A1**.

[image]